# What does QByteArray get converted to in QML?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qbytearray

If I have a

```
signal:
    void foo(QByteArray data);
```

And in QML I handle it:

```
 onFoo: {
     console.log(data.toString());
 }
```

What is the type of data in QML? What methods does it have? It doesn't seem to be a javascript string - it doesn't even have a `.length`, and no `.charCodeAt()`. But it also doesn't seem to be a `QByteArray` - no `.at()`. `data[0]` is `undefined`! It *does* have `.toString()`.

How do I access its contents? E.g. if it is a four-byte uint32_t, how do I get that number into a javascript variable?

Comment: There seems to be some development in getting QByteArray to ArrayBuffer conversion. Since it was merged just a few days ago we probably have to wait until Qt 5.8.
https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/144761/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>According to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html and the current source http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/qml/compiler/qqmltypecompiler.cpp.html#567, there's no conversion between QByteArray towards QML. You'll probably get an opaque, unaccesible Object in JS.</strike>

EDIT: The above was true up to Qt 5.8. 5.8 added a conversion between QByteArray and JS Array, see the other answer.

Needless to say: at the time of this writing, the only version you want to be using is >= 5.12.

Comment: Ok I guess I will have to make my own QObject-based type to wrap a QByteArray.

Comment: Please also add a suggestion in the bugtracker to add a mapping for QByteArray. It could get backed by a JS Array of some sorts.

Comment: Yep, it got outdated. Changing it.

Answer (score 8):

As stated in [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#qbytearray-to-javascript-arraybuffer) :

> The QML engine provides automatic type conversion between QByteArray
>   values and JavaScript ArrayBuffer objects.

This feature is available since Qt 5.8.